# PHP Regex replace expression inside two expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex expression to use with preg_replace() to replace a expression that's between two other expressions.
The overall idea is:

```
$new = "stuff";
$original = /*see below*/;
$final = preg_replace('regex expression', $new, $original);
```

example of $original string:

> (...)"dl cm = xxxx opop1 = XYZ opop3 = XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,"thisisit" YYYY = z"(...)

example of the $final string:

> (...)"dl cm = xxxx opop1 = XYZ opop3 = XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,"stuff" YYYY = z"(...)

(The X's, Y's, Z's can be any character)

The expression must find the 'opop3 = XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,"' then the following '"' and change the text inside this two delimiters.

I think that I found how to find the first delimiter

```
(opop3.=(.*)(\,)(.*)(\,)\")
```

And find the following '"' is not hard, but i don't know how can I change the text between them without touching the delimiters.

(or if someone know other way to do this, please, let me know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `\K` (reset search) of PCRE:

```
$final = preg_replace('/XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,"\K[^"]+/', $new, $original);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked!
$final = preg_replace("/opop3.*=.*,.*,"\K[^"]+/", "notinternet", $input_lines);